# can't create custom variant for MuiSelect

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-typescript

Theme:

```
  components: {
    MuiSelect: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: 'dashed' },
          style: {
            textTransform: 'none',
            border: `2px dashed red`,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
```

below

```
declare module '@mui/material/Select' {
  interface SelectPropsVariantOverrides {
    dashed: true;
  }
}
```

I do everything as here:
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#creating-new-component-variants

I get this error:

[image]

When I use their example - everything works but they use MuiButton, I need for MuiSelect

Comment: The error message says it. The select component only takes `outlined`, `filled`, and `standard` as the value for `variant` props, and you are assigning `dashed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the documentation: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/

You can only add prop variants to props that they allow you.

They say only those are allowd: 'filled'
| 'outlined'
| 'standard'

When they say **string** then you are allowed to add your custom prop variants.

Check this: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/

In section for 'size': they say: 'medium'
| 'small'
| string.   That string over there means you can add your custom variants, if the keyword string does not exist, you can't add custom prop variants

Comment: thanks for saying about string, I did not that

Answer (score 0):

Just found why I can't override MuiSelect:
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/29455